# CentOS command not found

Tags: centos, centos7, command-line-interface, grep

When I login to my CentOS 7 Server I get a couple of errors.

```
Similar command is: 'tty'
bash: ls: command not found...
Similar command is: 'lz'
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
```

Yesterday I tried to install the jre 9 by using this tutorial: `https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/09/22/install-oracle-java-9-centos-rhel/`.

My server don't recognize commands like `ls` or `yum`.
I tried to run `yum reinstall grep` but the response just was `bash: yum: Befehl nicht gefunden...` (command not found).

When I run `echo $PATH` the response is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools:/root/bin`.

Comment: It works for my session. Somehow does it not work in a new session. Do I have to save the PATH somehow? I'm using the ```export PATH=$PATH:/bin``` command.

Comment: Something's gone wrong with your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files. Edit these files and fix any problems.

Comment: I edited my ```/etc/environment``` file. It seems to work perfectly. Robert can you please write a solution to accept? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put /bin on the path.

You can make that permanent by editing your shell's configuration file. If you're using bash that would be .bashrc or .bash_profile, if you're using a different shell the file will be different.

Note that editing /etc/environment to add /bin will likely fix things regardless of the shell. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile) /etc/environment normally points to /bin amongst other things.

Comment: Yes, but editing `/etc/environment` just masks the problem. It's going to still be lurking out there somewhere.